Get DB2 AS400 version number
I am doing a migration from a DB2 AS400 to SQL Server 2014 database
I want to use SSMA for DB2 client (DB2ToSQL) migration tool
I need to find out if the DB2 version supports SSMA for DB2 client (DB2ToSQL)
I tried
db2ls
db2level
db2licm -l

but it responds with

SQL State: 42601 Vendor Code: -104 Message: [SQL0104] Token DB2LS was not valid. Valid tokens: ( CL END GET SET TAG CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER. Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token DB2LS.  Token DB2LS is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is ( CL END GET SET TAG CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER.  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token DB2LS. Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of clauses. -- If the error token is , correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause.   Processing ended because the highlighted statement did not complete successfully    Failed statements: 1

...and...
SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1


SQL State: 42704 Vendor Code: -204 Message: [SQL0204] GETVARIABLE in *LIBL type *N not found. Cause . . . . . :   GETVARIABLE in *LIBL type *N was not found. If the member name is *ALL, the table is not partitioned. If this is an ALTER TABLE statement and the type is *N, a constraint or partition was not found. If this is not an ALTER TABLE statement and the type is *N, a function, procedure, trigger or sequence object was not found. If a function was not found, GETVARIABLE is the service program that contains the function.  The function will not be found unless the external name and usage name match exactly.  A function is not considered as a candidate unless the user has the EXECUTE privilege for the function.  Examine the job log for a message that gives more details on which function name is being searched for and the name that did not match. Recovery  . . . :   Change the name and try the request again.  If the object is a node group, ensure that the DB2 Multisystem product is installed on your system and create a nodegroup with the CRTNODGRP CL command. If an external function was not found, be sure that the case of the EXTERNAL NAME on the CREATE FUNCTION statement exactly matches the case of the name exported by the service program.   Processing ended because the highlighted statement did not complete successfully    Failed statements: 1


ms-sql-server 2014  ...why are you migrating to an old version of SQL Server?

actually migrating to 2022

There were two answers on : SQL Query to Get DB2 Version on IBM i which provided the desired information.  Thank you.
